# Vuejs passing object to other route

Tags: vue.js

I am a beginner with Vue.js and I am facing an issue.

I have an object in one page, and, when clicked in a "detail" button to view details of this object I want to open another route with detailed infos about this object.

My problem is that I don't want to use route params to send the object to another view in another route because this will show the object in the URL. Neither do I want to use localStorage to store the object.

I was reading about vuex and props, but I don't think I understand how to use them in my case.

Comment: This is really too broad for Stack Overflow at the moment.  You should spend some time looking into vuex and build it into your application.  Once you have a more concrete question, come back and ask.  As is, this should be closed.

Comment: The usual way to do this would be to include an ID as part of the route URL, then in the 'Details' page load the rest of the object data based on that ID.  This has the advantage of allowing users to bookmark or directly link to that "details" page for a given object.

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks a lot! I Am a begginer in general with programming and had not realize that, dummy me! :D

Comment: I'm sorry but that sounds like a stupid way to do it considering the data is already loaded the the first route